# Join column (id) with a table in NestJS using TypeORM

Tags: nestjs, typeorm

I'm doing a server-side application in NodeJS and TypeORM.

I have these tables:

```
users
--------------------------------------------
 id        |  firstName            | lastName
--------------------------------------------
1          |  Lorem                | Ipsum

companies
------------------------------------------------------------
id        |  name
------------------------------------------------------------
1         |  Lorem

transfers
------------------------------------------------------------
id        |  points            | userId       | companyId
------------------------------------------------------------
1         |  10                | 1            | 1
```

CompanyEntity

```
@Entity({ name: 'companies' })
export class CompanyEntity extends BaseEntity {
  @Column()
  name: string;

  @OneToMany(() => TransferEntity, (transfer) => transfer.company)
  transfers: TransferEntity[];
}
```

TransferEntity

```
@Entity({ name: 'transfers' })
export class TransferEntity extends BaseEntity {
  @Exclude()
  @ManyToOne(() => CompanyEntity, (company) => company.transfers)
  company: CompanyEntity;

  @Column()
  points: number;

  @Column()
  userId: number;
}
```

Define a relationship between Transfers and Users is not an option for me.

I would like to get all the transfers of a company by its ID, and also, join the `userID` column with the real user with its data in the `users` table.

```
async findAllTransfersByCompanyId(id: number): Promise<TransferEntity[]> {
    // 1. Find the company by its ID
    const company = await this.companyRepository.findOne(id, {
      // 2. Get all the transfers
      relations: ['transfers'],
      // 3. Join the userId of a transfer with the user data in the 'users' table
      join: {
        alias: 'users',
        innerJoin: {
          userId: 'users.id',
        },
      },
    });

    return company.transfers;
  }
```

> Relation with property path id in entity was not found.

I don't understand well the logic to do joins, maybe there is an easiest way to do it.

My goal is to join the `userID` of the transfers table with the users table to return also its data in the response.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define the relationship between `transfers` and `users` just like you defined between `transfers` and `company`

```
@Entity({ name: 'transfers' })
export class TransferEntity extends BaseEntity {
  @Exclude()
  @ManyToOne(() => CompanyEntity, (company) => company.transfers)
  company: CompanyEntity;

  @Column()
  points: number;

  @ManyToOne((type) => User)
  user: User;
}
```

Comment: Define that relationship is not an option for me, that's why I didn't. I would like to do the relation in another way.